# How to read a huge single-line (100GB) with Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have a huge single-line (without line breaks) text file about 100GB.

The line has the following structure:

```
|<--500 characters-->|<--500 characters-->|<--500 characters-->|...
```

I would like to break the line every 500 characters and construct a spark RDD/DATAFRAME where the nth element is the nth 500 characters:

```
|<--500 characters-->|
|<--500 characters-->|
|<--500 characters-->|
|...
```

I know that I can change the line separator, but it dosent solve my use case

```
spark.read.option("LineSep", some_line_separator).textFile(path_to_my_file)
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a single huge records file, you should read it as binary records, assuming you have a fixed length character encoding, and then convert it as String:

```
// adjust the encoding as necessary
val charset = "US-ASCII"
// adjust the record size based on encoding length if necessary
val recordSize = 500 
val ds = sparkContext
    .binaryRecords("yourFilePath", recordSize) 
    .map(record => new String(record, charset))
    .toDS()
```

The [FixedLengthBinaryInputFormat](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/input/FixedLengthBinaryInputFormat.scala) used will ensure the file is correctly split across the executors.

Comment: I thought of doing it with lambda with list comprehension. Is binaryRecords way is  really fast? any idea about conf parameter for this.. seems optional in this case. Thanks

Comment: binaryRecords will split the records across the executors so the performance will scale with the cluster resources and should be faster than lambda. The third `conf` parameter is for providing a custom hadoopConfiguration. If not provided, Spark will use its default hadoop conf which should be OK in most cases.

Comment: Thank you, this solution works, I had to downgrade the guava version to 15.0 because I got IllegalAccessError to guava's StopWatch from org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus, but now I cannot  run gcs-connector because need recent version of guava

Comment: could you suggest a way to do this in pyspark.. facing some issues

Comment: pyspark should work pretty much the same way except you'll probably want to cast to string using the build-in `Column.cast` method after conversion to DataFrame for performance reasons